# Hair is inside the chin but not outside

Tags: weight-painting, normals, hair

I try to make fur around the mouth of a fantasy creature, but the hair on chin is in the inside. I don't have make anything with the particle edit yet, I'm still in the weight painting.

[image]

I thought the normals are the problem. But according to edit they are on the right side.

[image]

In the inside there are no normals of the chin, only teeth, tongue, etc.

[image]

But I can't make any hair on the chin, because the hair is inside. Does somebody know what the problem is and how can I solve it?
I have try to delete the weight paint in the inside, but when I do this, the weight paint on the outside is gone, too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to estimate the problem while not having the .blend file.

However I guess the normals could be the issue. Maybe try to check normals with colouring options, the drawn line often gets a bit messy.

Also, you could have bad geometry on you model which leads to the error - probaly try the '3D-Print Toolbox' Add-on, press 'f3' and run the command '3D-Print Clean Non-Manifold' - then check the normals again, maybe it helps